# How to fix jagged edges of controls (buttons, autocomplete text)?

Tags: android, button, rendering

I am developing my first Android application. I have created a relativelayout with two buttons and one autocomplete text view. The three controls display correctly on the emulator. However, when I create the apk file and install it on my Samsung Galaxy 5, the buttons show jagged edges, and the top and bottom lines 'sink' a bit and the text view gets an appearance of rounded square brackets on either side with horizontal edges sunk by a half millimeter or so.

Any help in understanding what is happening and how to fix it is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?  I'm having a hard time visualizing what you are describing.

Comment: Please show us your layout xml

Comment: Are you using custom drawables for the buttons?

Comment: @mbaird

@WarrenFaith

@Robby

Please refer to my next reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer. It was perhaps because I had not defined Minimum SDK version and target SDK version in the manifest (uses-sdk node).

Adding the following two attributes to the uses-sdk node in manifest file solved the issue. I hope this is what was really necessary.

```
android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="7"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that Samsung is using their own theme in your app. You can override this theme by making one yourself.

This will help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html